# Glide with recyclerview auto scrolling to the bottom

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am using glide to load images into the recyclerview item. Now that the images are loaded and when I try scrolling up, it goes up for a bit and then auto scrolls to the bottom on it's own. Seems like it's got something to do with the requests being sent by  Glide to load the images which is clashing with scrolling event of the recyclerview.

**Here's my code to load the images**

```
Glide.with(context).load(avatar_url)
               .placeholder(R.drawable.dummy_image_background)
               .crossFade()
               .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
               .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                       drawable = resource;
                       holder.imageViewMessage.setImageDrawable(resource);
                   }
               });
```

Comment: can share your complete code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **Universal Image Loader** instead of **Glide** and it amazingly solved my problem.